# How do I print a date without also printing the time in Java?

Tags: java, date, time, simpledateformat

```
try {

            System.out.println("Please enter a start date and an end date for your stay (dd/mm/yyyy): ");
            startDate = sdf.parse(input.next());
            endDate = sdf.parse(input.next());

            long diff = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
            int diffInt = (int) (diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));


        if (diffInt == 7 || diffInt == 14) {
            System.out.println("Your reservation has been successfully booked for "+startDate+" until "+endDate);
            break;
        }

        } catch (ParseException e) {

            System.out.println("You have entered an invalid date range. Please try again.");
            e.printStackTrace();

        } //END OF TRY-CATCH
```

This is the code I have so far. What I am doing is getting input for two dates from the user, then using those dates to figure out how many days there are between them. If there are either 7 or 14 days between the two dates they have selected, then it is successful.

It works well so far but the only problem is when this line is executed:

```
System.out.println("Your reservation has been successfully booked for "+startDate+" until "+endDate);
            break;
```

When it prints out the variables, it prints out the date plus "00:00:00 GMT" which I don't want.

To be honest I don't like how it prints out the date like "Tue Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT" which isn't great either. I would rather it look how it's input e.g. 01/01/2019.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: consider using (not so) new date/time classes from [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) package, like [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) (Note: the calculation this code is doing can be affected by Daylight Saving Time)

Comment: It seems you are using `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. I recommend you don’t do that. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Also despite the name a `Date` is not a date but a point in time. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to look at [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Instantiate yourself a `SimpleDateFormat` with the desired output format e.g. `new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")` and then simply use the `format(java.util.Date)` method to convert your date objects to strings in your desired format. In your code example above this would probably get you your desired output:

```
...
DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String startDateString = outputFormat.format(startDate);
String endDateString = outputFormat.format(endDate);
System.out.println("Your reservation has been successfully booked for "+startDateString+" until "+endDateString);
...
```

Comment: Of course it was that god damn simple haha. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.